# How to parse ul , li tags in android studio using jsoup without div and display it in recycler view?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve the data from web page and the sample html code is shown below I want to retrieve the data and show it in list view.

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Index of /abc/xyz/Female/pqr</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <h1>Index of /abc/xyz/Female/pqr</h1> 
  <ul>
   <li><a href="//abc/xyz/Female/pqr"> Parent Directory</a></li> 
   <li><a href="2016060500004.png"> 2016060500004.png</a></li> 
   <li><a href="2016060500011.png"> 2016060500011.png</a></li> 
   <li><a href="2016060500012.png"> 2016060500012.png</a></li> 
</ul>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select ul use this :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements ul = doc.select("ul"); // select ul
```

refer to docs here: [Jsoup docs](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Example :

```
String html = "<html>"+
"<head>"+
"<title>Index of /abc/xyz/Female/pqr</title>"+
"</head>"+
"<body>"+
"<h1>Index of /abc/xyz/Female/pqr</h1>"+
"<ul>" +
"<li><a href=\"//abc/xyz/Female/pqr\"> Parent Directory</a></li>"+
"<li><a href=\"2016060500004.png\"> 2016060500004.png</a></li>"+
"<li><a href=\"2016060500011.png\"> 2016060500011.png</a></li>"+
"<li><a href=\"2016060500012.png\"> 2016060500012.png</a></li>"+
"</ul>" +
"</body>"+
"</html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements links = doc.select("ul"); // select ul

for(Element b : links){
    System.out.println(b.text());
}
```

Comment: In this example there is div . In my example there is no div, Its starting directly with ul

Comment: you are most welcome :) and I included a specific solution to ur example just in case you needed it